# AsyncHttpResponseHandler class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method android

Tags: java, android, web-services, restful-url

[Following this tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-call-restful-webservice-in-android-part-3/)

But I am getting the error on below code AsyncHttpResponseHandler says AsyncHttpResponseHandler class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method android

client.get("http://192.168.2.2:9999/useraccount/login/dologin",params ,new **AsyncHttpResponseHandler**()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [official doc](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) ,the correct implementation is :

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("http://www.google.com", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```